# How to add Transparency information to a HEX color code?

Tags: javascript, math, colors

I have to modify some code and the previous developer left this comment:

```
color: color, // e.g. '#RRGGBBFF' - Last 2 digits are alpha information
```

On the page there is a color picker that let's the user change text color. It gives HEX values like so:

```
#RRGGBB
```

And there is a slider that allows the user to change a text's transparency. It runs from `0.1` to `1`

Somehow I need to get a 2 digit letter from this transparency amount and append it to the HEX value for it to work.

**Does anyone know how to append Alpha information to HEX color codes? What is the math formula for it?**

I guess the question can also be answered if anyone knows how to convert RGBA color values with transparency into HEX:

```
rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)
```

Answer (score 22):

This [is nice function](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/javascript+add+alpha+to+hex)

```
function addAlpha(color, opacity) {
    // coerce values so it is between 0 and 1.
    var _opacity = Math.round(Math.min(Math.max(opacity ?? 1, 0), 1) * 255);
    return color + _opacity.toString(16).toUpperCase();
}
addAlpha('FF0000', 1); // returns 'FF0000FF'
addAlpha('FF0000', 0.5); // returns 'FF000080'
```

Comment: My test fails for this function 
`expect(addAlphaToHex('#000000', 0)).toBe('#00000000');` what I received is `#000000FF`. If opacity is 0 I think the test is wrong in Math.max. I added a test before `if(!opacity)...`

Answer (score 16):

Based on Paul's answer here is a one-line ECMA6 function which receives `hex` color and `alpha` and return the calculated `hex` color:

```
const setOpacity = (hex, alpha) => `${hex}${Math.floor(alpha * 255).toString(16).padStart(2, 0)}`;
```

Comment: this is great! but note `padStart`'s type def `padStart(maxLength: number, fillString?: string): string;` updating the last chain to `.padStart(2, '0')` achieved same result for me

Answer (score 8):

A two-digit **hex**adecimal number has a maximum value of `255 = (16 ** 2 - 1)` and minimum of `0`, your *alpha* has maximum `1` and minimum `0`, so it's a simple matter of

```
// say we start with        e.g. alpha = 0.3
x = alpha * 255;  // float, e.g. x = 76.5
```

this won't always be an integer, so you'll most likely want to convert it to one, for example using

```
y = Math.floor(x);  // int, e.g. y = 76
```

converting this into a base-16 string will give you your desired output

```
s = y.toString(16); // str, e.g. s = "4c"
```

finally, if `y < 16` this will only be one digit, so you may need to pad an extra  `0`

```
ret = y < 16 ? '0' + s : s;
```

Comment: `.toString(16)` as well more than likely. And don't forget padding :)

Comment: This will just make another color, with alpha=1

Answer (score 1):

As always, use linear scaling.

(vald - mind) / (maxd - mind) * (maxr - minr) + minr

(0.1 - 0.0) / (1.0 - 0.0) * (255 - 0) + 0 = 25.5 ~= 0x1a

Answer (score 1):

the answer from user956584 has a problem with opacities near 0 or 0.  (they are converted to 100% alpha). I fixed it here

```
function changeColorAlpha(color, opacity) 
{
    //if it has an alpha, remove it
    if (color.length > 7)
        color = color.substring(0, color.length - 2);

    // coerce values so ti is between 0 and 1.
    const _opacity = Math.round(Math.min(Math.max(opacity, 0), 1) * 255);
    let opacityHex = _opacity.toString(16).toUpperCase()

    // opacities near 0 need a trailing 0
    if (opacityHex.length == 1)
        opacityHex = "0" + opacityHex;

    return color + opacityHex;
}
console.log(changeColorAlpha('#FFFFFF00', 0));  // return "#FFFFFF00"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gomador/5wfvrpxa/12/

Answer (score 0):

Per the [relevant portion of the W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color), there is no hex version of RGBA values.  Quoting from that spec:

> Unlike RGB values, there is no hexadecimal notation for an RGBA value.

So, the work-around is that you use the `rgba(r, g, b, a)` format or you set transparency separately.

Answer (score -1):

If using for web dev, as referred in Learn to code HTML&CSS written by Shay Howe, HEX color is the most popular but when transparency needed we have to use RGBa or HSLa. RGBa has more support than HSLa.